# Write a function that will count the number of words in a file. JAva in Eclipse. the file is a list of words (not sentences)

Tags: java, eclipse, wordle-game

I am a little stuck, here's the code I have so far. My professor does Not want us to change these two: Write a function that will count the number of words in a file.  Use this contract and method header.  (Do not change the method contract or header.) so i did forget to create main (sorry I am a beginner).
After Fixing everything it is still not printing the number of words. what have i missed?

```js
public class WordleClone
{

    public static int main(String[] args) 
    {

        String filename = "five.txt";
        countWords(filename);
        
        return 0;

    }
    
    /**
     * Given a filename, this method returns a count of the number of
     * words in the file.  (Note that word length is not checked here.)
     * 
     * @param filename the name of an existing text file
     * @return the count of words in the file
     */
        public static int countWords (String filename)
                {
                
                
                File file = new File(filename);
                try (Scanner in = new Scanner(file))
                {
                    int countWords =0;
                    while(in.hasNext())
                    {
                        in.next();
                        countWords++;
                    
                    }
                   System.out.println(countWords);
                    
                    return countWords;
                }
            
            
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            return -1;
                
            }
            
       }
}
```

here's what I have including the header and contract.

here's a previous of the list, it's a long column of words:

```
Aaron
aback
abaft
abase
abash
abate
abbey
abbot
abeam
abele
abets
```

Comment: And where are you stuck? Why is the output of the program given not the correct output?

Comment: Looks like this is only missing a return statement?

Answer (score 0):

`int countWords (String filename)` means that there will be a method called `countWords` which will accept a filename as a parameter and then should return an `int`.

Your code does not return anything and hence will not compile. You should also use the parameter to open the file.

```
File file = new File(filename);
```

But declaring the `count` variable in the `try` will means that its scope is limited to the `try` block.  Should declare before the `try` block so that you can return it.

```
return count;
```

Comment: i fixed the code but it is still not printing the code

Comment: Because it is not running. `public static int main(String[] args)` should be `public static void main(String[] args) `